# How to detect that a C/C++ file is using windows specific stuff

Tags: c++, c, testing, automated-tests

Basically I want to test files/libraries/code in general that wont run on Linux by detecting windows specific includes, program calls, dynamically linked libraries at runtime, anything that isn't Linux compatible.
This is to make sure that the resulting program always works under Linux.
I also have to automate this

Thanks!

Edit: I'm talking about source code, not compiled binaries but if some code uses a pre-compiled library i would need to check that when in uses it, it works on Linux

Edit2: I dont know much about C/C++ test suites but compiling and evaluating every line, including all the conditional branches should be posible, this and checking that the linked binary libs are compatible from a list of known libs could work rigth?

Comment: So you want to check source code, compiled libraries and compiled executables to ensure they are Linux compatible. Is that correct?

Comment: On SO you need to give specific examples of what your problem is and what you have tried. Your current question is to broard.

Comment: Remove all `#include <windows.h>` and compile - this will get you to 90%.  Then build on Linux (use a VM if needed) with the native only tool-chain (not MinGW, or Wine etc) - this will get you to 100%.

Comment: You might be onto a losing battle. Ordinarily, `#include <windows.h>` could be a good start. However, it exists in Wine ([here](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/master/include/windows.h)) so that will not always be true.

Comment: In edit one, you say "if some code uses a pre-compiled library i would need to check that when in uses it, it works on Linux". Why? Are Windows libraries finding their way onto your machine and getting mixed up with Linux libraries?

Comment: Whatever pre-compiled library it would contain would have to be recompiled oor replaced with linux binaries. Windows binaries will not work even for the same cpu

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there's an exact way of doing that. Still, you can try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f -name "*.cpp" | xargs cat | grep "windows.h"
find . -type f -name "*.h" | xargs cat | grep "windows.h"
find . -type f -name "*.hpp" | xargs cat | grep "windows.h"
find . -type f -name "*.cc" | xargs cat | grep "windows.h"
find . -type f -name "*.cxx" | xargs cat | grep "windows.h"
find . -type f -name "*.cpp" | xargs cat | grep "winsock.h"
...
```

After that, you set your current directory to the root of the project, and run the script. If the output is empty, you're fine.

Problem here is building up a list of headers, but that can be googled pretty easily.

This solution won't get you to 100%, but, after a number of iterations, it will be very close to 99,9%.

To further automate this, you could check the output for being empty, and return 0 or 1 based on the result.

Checking all the macros for #ifdef _WIN32 and stuff like that... Well, you need to build your own sort of compiler for that, I don't know if this stuff exists.